# How i can make this container in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How i can make this container in flutter??

```
 Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    final halfWidth = size.width / 2;
    final halfSpace = space / 2;
    final curve = space / 6;
    final height = halfSpace / 1.4;
    path.lineTo(halfWidth - halfSpace, 0);
    path.cubicTo(halfWidth - halfSpace, 0, halfWidth - halfSpace + curve,
        height, halfWidth, height);
    path.cubicTo(halfWidth, height, halfWidth + halfSpace - curve, height,
        halfWidth + halfSpace, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path.close();
    return path;
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please see here where i have created custom path like this in https://github.com/11Shraddha/CustomShapedBottomBar.

[image: Custom Shaped Bottom Bar1]